# How to a access nvme ssd with raid mode in bios settings?

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme, m.2

I know the real answer is to set ahci in uefi settings, but in my case, the uefi is password protected (the problem is not removing the password but actually keeping it).

I can also add that the Windows installed on the nvme has no problem using them.

But with the same settings on Linux, the ssd doesn t even appear as a pci device even with `nvme_load=YES` on the command line.

So as I don t have my own computer, how to access the free space on the local nvme from my Linux live usb disk?

Comment: I have a similar issue with the new Dell 9700: if I set the SATA to AHCI then the Windows installation is borked (but Linux can install fine) but if I set it to RAID Windows is fine, but Linux can't find it. So I'm forced to choose, and can't have a small Windows partition for occasional use :-(

Comment: For *my* problem I was able to convert the RAID on Windows to AHCI: 
https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10