# Raid 0 to ahci /not just the mode, the setup as well/

Tags: raid, ahci

So, my laptop is a MSI gt73vr 6re.
My os sits on a raid 0, consists of 2*256gb nvme.
I need more space, but on a budget, so I will swap a 256gb nvme to a 1tb nvme.
I read this post:
[Switch RAID to AHCI without reinstalling Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10)
My concern is that I am not simply in raid mode, but my os actually installed on a raid 0 made of 2 separate disc.
Would that be destroyed if I change to ahci?
I made an image with windows, onto the hdd I have, which is a dynamic disc.

My plan is to install the 1tb nvme, then set the bios from raid to ahci, with a windows repair disc boot up, and from that restore my system with the image on the hdd which is a dynamic disc.

So the questions:

- can the boot repair take care of the change in raid from ahci?|
- would the windows install see the dynamic disc at all?
- would this plan work at all?
  Thanks in advance!