# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE in Windows 10 after changing SATA Configuration from RAID ON to AHCI

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, bsod, sata, dualboot

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dual Boot Windows 10 Alienware Laptop. At first, the live Ubuntu installer couldn't detect the SSD inside so I changed the SATA configuration from RAID ON to AHCI. I could install Ubuntu without any problem after that.

However, because of changing to AHCI, now Windows 10 is not booting up and showing INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE. Luckily, I was able to boot Windows 10 even after installing Ubuntu by changing the SATA configuration back to RAID ON. Then I followed steps written [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/933042/569883) and changed "Storage Controllers" from Intel to Microsoft. Finally, I changed back to AHCI in boot options.

Later on, I also installed the [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on Ubuntu thinking that it will solve the issue. However, I still can not log in to Windows 10.

Any workaround, please?

Comment: Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work after booting Windows 10 in safe mode for once. After that, it worked well.

Please read the complete instructions from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1359471).